# the TTTwitter seems to be wrong in the three20 example

Tags: three20

the TTTwitter seems to be wrong,when i click the more Button,the following method runs twice,and first time more is true,second time more is false,so we can see that the table can't load data right.

```
- (void)load:(TTURLRequestCachePolicy)cachePolicy more:(BOOL)more
```

anyone can  help me ? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the cache and see if it helps you. Three20 cache is a little broken. Look for a line that declares the cache in the model's load function and change it to:

```
request.cachePolicy = TTURLRequestCachePolicyNone;
```

Comment: thank you very much ,it works well.but what's the cache function?they can let the load:more method runs twice ,so unexpected

Comment: the cache is responsible to save a copy of the results to the iPhone memory. so if you load another request from twitter, it will use the memory and not send a request to twitter.